# Getting function variable in PHP

Tags: php

I have a function and I want to check the status of it and echo the return.:

```
if (insert($order, $items, $depot) !== false) {
    echo json_encode(array('response'=>'success','message'=>'Order #'.$insert().' successfully placed.'));
}else{
    echo json_encode(array('response'=>'danger','message'=>'Order failed'));   
}
```

If the function passes it returns the order ID, if it fails it returns a fail. I am having trouble with the second line, how do I echo the value it is returning?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
if (($orderId = insert($order, $items, $depot)) !== false) {
    echo json_encode(array('response'=>'success','message'=>'Order #'.$orderId.' successfully placed.'));
}else{
    echo json_encode(array('response'=>'danger','message'=>'Order failed'));   
}
```

OR

```
$orderId = insert($order, $items, $depot);
if ($orderId !== false) {
    echo json_encode(array('response'=>'success','message'=>'Order #'.$orderId.' successfully placed.'));
}else{
    echo json_encode(array('response'=>'danger','message'=>'Order failed'));   
}
```

Comment: did you test this?

Comment: yes I'm using it all the time, the first method i think doen't work in php version 5.6 or less but not sure

Comment: Shouldn't you include the version in your answer?

Comment: I'm not sure that's why I didn't put it, waiting someone to confirm and edit answer

Comment: Seems that extra set of parenthesis did trick Youssef. Though I would have thought that the assignment `=` had priority

Comment: Looks good, just as a personal preference, I wouldnt change the variable name in the second example, just to keep it consistent I'd use `$orderId` for both